# Узнать номер строки по значению. SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

начал изучить sqlite3 и не могу найти как узнать номер строки по значению и возможно ли это. Например есть таблица:

```
  Id|Name
1|11|user1
2|15|user2
3|17|user3
```

и нужно узнать на какой строке расположено число 15 в колонке 'Id'

Comment: Ну как я понимаю, нет такого отдельного понятия — номер строки. У вас значит должна быть отдельная колонка, в которую записывается очередной номер. И тогда уже можно получить строку.

Comment: А, понял. Не подскажете как?

Comment: Оказывается, всё-таки можно получить номер строки https://stackoverflow.com/a/51863033/7485582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно с помощью Window Function `ROW_NUMBER()`.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f3f960f146af9d8b29da32956d83112f)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE mock (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO mock (ID, Name) VALUES
(11, 'user1'),
(15, 'user2'),
(17, 'user3');

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
, ID, Name
FROM mock;
```

**Результат**

```
+---------+-----+-------+
| RowNum  | ID  | Name  |
+---------+-----+-------+
|      1  | 11  | user1 |
|      2  | 15  | user2 |
|      3  | 17  | user3 |
+---------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: по-моему, в данном примере лучше идентифицировать строки по столбцу `Id`. Представьте себе, что в эту таблицу вставили строку с `Id = 2` - все номера строк, полученные при помощи `ROW_NUMBER()`  - "поедут"