# Как записать данные в определенную строку определенного столбца?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Возможно ли записать данные в определенную строку определенного столбца?

Например:

```
  Id|Name
1|11|user1
2|15|
3|17|user3
4|25|user4
```

В строчку 2 под столбец 'Name' записать 'user2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать порядковые номера строк в реляционных БД нельзя, т.к. они могут измениться.

Например если после удаления нескольких строк сделать `VACUUM`, то SQLite удалит "дырки", чтобы сделать БД более компактной. После этого номера всех строк, располагавшихся после первой дырки (удаленной строки) изменятся.

Все операции изменения строк желательно выполнять по первичному ключу (Primary Key), который обязан быть уникальным.

Судя по вашим данным, столбец `Id` - выполняет у вас роль первичного ключа. Поэтому гораздо безопаснее и правильнее идентифицировать записи по столбцу `Id`:

```
sqlite> select * from tab;
Id  Name
--  -----
11  user1
15
17  user3
25  user4

sqlite> update tab set name = 'user2' where id = 15 and name is null;

sqlite> select * from tab;
Id  Name
--  -----
11  user1
15  user2
17  user3
25  user4
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1240601/235436 Вроде можно использовать доп. таблицу для поиска Id нужной строки

Comment: @КириллМалышев, можно, но зачем?

Comment: таков вопрос...

Comment: @КириллМалышев, именно поэтому я и написал свой ответ - чтобы показать как правильно работать с данными в реляционных БД. Чтобы не было потом мучительно больно... ;) PS и вообще мне кажется этот вопрос из серии вопросов "XY problem"

Comment: @КириллМалышев, веселый пример - что произойдет со всеми  номерами строк   из ответа по вашей ссылке, если вставить строку с `Id = 1` ? ;)

Comment: Ну я так понимаю, там специально задаётся сортировка. Если хочется по времени сортировать строки, надо просто добавить datetime-поле. Это уже от целей всё зависит.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, ну представьте себе что строку с `id = 2` вставил другой пользователь - в итоге если делать замену по "номеру строки" мы заменим не ту строку. В общем существует много причин, по которым не стоит идентифицировать строки по их порядковому номеру (даже с учетом сортировки)

Answer (score 1):

Insert into users value(name) where id=? ; и под вопрос подставляете что вам надо

Comment: в этом ответе несколько ошибок - как логических, так и синтаксических

Comment: insert into users(name) value(?) where id=? Хм а так

Comment: Update users set name=? Where id =? Или так