# Как добавить данные в определенную ячейку SQLite?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня есть функция которая должная добавлять определенную информацию, эта информация содержится в кнопку inline. тоесть мне нужно при нажатии кнопки вписать это в БД

```
def add_ts(self, user_id, trading_style):
    with self.connection:
        try:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id', 'trading_style') VALUES (?, ?)", (trading_style,))
        except:
            pass
```

так выглядит таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так хендлер который обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку и пытается добавить эти данные в таблицу. Нужно для каждого нового пользователя добавлять данные в ячейку trading_style в зависимости от того на какую из трех кнопок он нажал

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="cratcosrochnaya")
async def cratcosrochnaya(message: types.Message, trading_style="ST"):
    await db.add_ts(message.from_user.id, trading_style)
    await bot.delete_message(message.from_user.id, message.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Текст для Краткосрочная")
```

Что я делаю не так? объясните плиз

Comment: Я дописал что это асинхронная функция т.к. была с этим ошибка связана, но данные все равно не записываются в бд

Comment: убрал try и получил ошибку: sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.user_id

Но я передаю в запросе переменную trading_style как вы помните, а на ней нет ограничений, есть только на usdr_id. Как сделать вопрос так чтобы небыло ошибки?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240605/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0